# How to pass rendered plot to a html file through render_template?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, server

I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460112/10765156), and I want to use render_template to call my html file instead of running plot in my py directly.

I want to use something like:

```
return render_template('hello.html', plot_url)
```

instead of:

```
return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(plot_url)
```

My question is, if there is any way to pass plot to html file and then run it in flask?

Edit:

```
@app.route('/')
def build_Plot():
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    x = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(output, format='png')
    output.seek(0)
    plot_data = base64.b64encode(output.getvalue()).decode()
    return render_template("home.html", url=plot_data)
```

and in home.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MyFlaskApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
            <img src="data:image/png;base64 = {{ url }} "/>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, pay enough attention to your html file name, I see two different names, `hello.html` and `home.html`. Then try to use [matplotlib.backends.backend_agg](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_agg_api.html) as follows:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from io import BytesIO
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
@app.route('/')
def build_Plot():
    output = io.BytesIO()
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    x = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    f = plt.figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(f)
    canvas.print_png(output)
    plot_data= b64encode(output.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
    output.seek(0)
    return render_template("home.html", url=plot_data)
```

In this way, it has the canvas write to an in-memory file, and the resulting PNG data is then encoded to base64 and interpolated in a data URL.

Comment: It worked! I made a bit change and now working as I expected. Thank yooou very much

Answer (score 1):

`plot_url` actually stores is an URL to an image. So if you already have a HTML page like hello.html, you can do this while rendering it:

hello.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MyFlaskApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
            {% if plot %}
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{url}}">
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

In the Python file, you can do the below:

```
return render_template("hello.html",plot=True, url=plot_url)
```

Note the plot_url comes from the `base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()` line mentioned in the answer you've linked.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I run page using my solution it works, but with your solution doesn't load any plot in local host page

Comment: Just made a change, could you try that? Added an extra pair of braces around url.

Comment: Gives me error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Comment: Latest edit please, I'm so sorry for the stupid error.

Comment: Unfortunatly doesn't load the plot again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to be passing the image along with the page (instead of including a url in the `img` tag, ghe format of data URLs suggests that you need

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ data }}" />
```

where `data` is a base64-encoding of a PNG representation of the image.

But if you mean to be passing in a URL, then you'd want something like

```
<img src="{{ url }}" />
```

where `url` is a link back to a view method in your app that will return a non-base64-encoded image.

Comment: I tried your solution but get this in response: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2018 23:40:03] "GET /iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCA.......hAAAAAy/w/eHm5zQpnsLwAAAAASUVORK5CYII= HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: With the second one, it just gets a long sting rather than a number like 223 or 404... and doesn't load the plot in the local page

Comment: I provided two solutions. It looks like you tried passing a base64-encoded image (which is what the first solution wants) to the second.

Comment: In my code, `plot_url = base64.b64encode(output.getvalue()).decode()` and `type(plot_url)`==`<type 'unicode'>` . Don't know what should I do!! I am using `plot_url` with that format because I want a dynamic plot.

Comment: Then, assuming that `output.getvalue()` is really a PNG, `<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ plot_url }}" />` is what you want, though the name `plot_url` is misleading. It's really `plot_data`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to show us the code that leads up to `output`.

Comment: Change `data:image/png;base64 = {{ url }}` to `data:image/png;base64,{{ url }}`