# Python - Flask - MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I am trying to embed a plot from a function that I pass into my flask application.

The below does everything fine but launches the plot outside of the browser.

I've read a lot about IO and all but I'm confused on how/where to handle that.

The function runBB() in app.py returns plt.show(). After being passed symbol which is retrieved from the form. Should I be passing fig instead to do the IO calculations in app.py or should I do that in the file that holds the function?

I don't want to save the file anywhere as I want this to be dynamic from the stand point of multiple not overwriting the saved file which is what IO gets around I believe.

app.py

```
#Dashboard page
@app.route("/dashboard", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def dashboard():
    if person["is_logged_in"] == True:
        return render_template("dashboard.html", email = person["email"], name = person["name"])
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route("/form", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def form():
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form["symbol"]
        bytes_obj = runBB(symbol)

        return render_template("dashboard.html", symbol=bytes_obj)
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'dashboard.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/dashboard.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <h1 class="name">Hi, {{name}}</h1>

    <form action="{{ url_for('form') }}" method ="POST">
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your symbol" type="text" name="symbol"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Run Report" class="btn-default"></p>
    </form>

    <P>{{bytes_obj}}</P>

    <!-- <hr style="width: 30%"> -->
    <h3 class="email">{{email}}</h3>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I've tried to comprehend other similar stackoverflow questions and can't seem to grasp this or put it together.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460112/42346 That's one way you can get this done.

Comment: web pages work different then desktop programs and matplotlib was created to work on desktop, not on web page. But there is module [mpl3d](https://mpld3.github.io/) which uses javascript module D3.js to generate Matplotlib plot for HTML page.

Comment: @mechanical_meat so would I just have the function return plt so when I call the function  in app.py I can get plt and save it with in app.py?

Comment: @rossinbossin: it's a little more involved than that. Alternatively maybe look into mpl3d like furas is talking about.

Comment: @furas I looked into mpld3 and tried a few concepts I might have to revisit that.

Comment: you can also try to use plotly instead of matplotlib - see [plotlyjs-flask-example](https://github.com/plotly/plotlyjs-flask-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this link to learn how to do this using:

```
import io
import base64
```

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1924163